# How to set Audio Focus ChangeListener in Android API O?

Tags: java, android

Since `requestAudioFocus(AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener l, int streamType, int durationHint)` is deprecated in API O , how do you set audio focus change listener using AudioFocusRequest

Comment: I checked [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html) but it does not seem to be deprecated. Also there was no any deprecated warning in AndroidStudio.

Comment: Check here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#requestAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, int, int).

Answer (score 22):

See the [Official Android Audio Focus Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus)

```
 AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
                .setAudioAttributes(
                        new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                                .build()
                )
                .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
                .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                       //Handle Focus Change 
                    }
                }).build()
        );
    } else {

        mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(focusChange -> {

                   //Handle Focus Change for earliest version of oreo
                },
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use AudiomanagerCompat together with AudioAttributesCompat and AudioRequestCompat, all part of Jetpack (androidx) compatibility libraries: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/AudioManagerCompat

In this way, you can use the same code for Android O+ and also for previous versions (without conditional checks on the API version.
But one of the drawbacks of this approach is that you can't use: .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)

If you decide for this approach, then you have to use requestAudioFocus(mAudioManager, mFocusRequest) and abandonAudioFocusRequest(mAudioManager, mFocusRequest) to obtain and release audio focus.

Partial sample code (in Kotlin): 
(Note: if you do not use Timber for logging, replace it by the standard Log function)

```
class MyClass : AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    internal var audioManager: AudioManager? = null
    private var focusRequest: AudioFocusRequestCompat? = null
    private var playbackAttributes : AudioAttributesCompat? = null

    // Create AudioManager and other audio related objects
    audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?
    playbackAttributes = AudioAttributesCompat.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributesCompat.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributesCompat.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build()

    focusRequest = AudioFocusRequestCompat.Builder(AudioManagerCompat.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
                .setAudioAttributes(playbackAttributes ?: return)
                .setWillPauseWhenDucked(false)
                .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(this)
                .build()

    // Request audio focus and check if it was granted to us
    if (requestAudioFocus(audioManager!!, focusRequest!!) == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
         // We obtained audio focus

    }
    else {
        // We could not obtain audio focus

    }

    // And to remove audio focus
    if (audioManager != null && focusRequest != null)
            abandonAudioFocusRequest(audioManager!!, focusRequest!!)



    // Implementation of OnAudioFocusChangeListener
    override fun onAudioFocusChange(focusState: Int) {

        // Invoked when the audio focus of the system is updated.
        when (focusState) {
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN -> {
                // We recovered audio focus.
                Timber.d("Audio Focus obtained")
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS -> {
                // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time
                Timber.d("Audio Focus lost")
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK -> {
                // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing at an attenuated level
                Timber.d("Audio Focus transient loss - can duck")
            }
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT -> {
                // Lost focus for a short time
                Timber.d("Audio Focus transient loss - cannot duck")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What I have founded in official docs:

> Explicit requests for audio focus: Your service can submit a more
> fine-grained request for receiving device-wide audio focus by using
> the requestAudioFocus() method. Pass in an AudioFocusRequest object,
> which you create using AudioFocusRequest.Builder. In this builder
> class, you can specify the following options:
>
> The type of focus you wish to gain, such as AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT
> or AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK. Whether your service should
> continue more quietly or pause completely when another audio service
> takes over device focus. Whether your service can wait to gain focus
> until the device is ready.
>
> Note: When building your instance of
> AudioFocusRequest, if you indicate that your service can wait to
> produce sound by calling setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(), you must also
> call setOnAudioFocusChangeListener() so that your service knows when
> it can begin producing sound.

As @kelebro63 mentioned the following example shows how to use an `AudioFocusRequest.Builder` to build an `AudioFocusRequest` and request and abandon audio focus:

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mPlaybackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build();
mFocusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        .setAudioAttributes(mPlaybackAttributes)
        .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(mMyFocusListener, mMyHandler)
        .build();
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
final Object mFocusLock = new Object();

boolean mPlaybackDelayed = false;
boolean mPlaybackNowAuthorized = false;

// ...
int res = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mFocusRequest);
synchronized(mFocusLock) {
    if (res == AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) {
        mPlaybackNowAuthorized = false;
    } else if (res == AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
        mPlaybackNowAuthorized = true;
        playbackNow();
    } else if (res == AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_DELAYED) {
       mPlaybackDelayed = true;
       mPlaybackNowAuthorized = false;
    }
}

// ...
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            if (mPlaybackDelayed || mResumeOnFocusGain) {
                synchronized(mFocusLock) {
                    mPlaybackDelayed = false;
                    mResumeOnFocusGain = false;
                }
                playbackNow();
            } 
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            synchronized(mFocusLock) {
                mResumeOnFocusGain = false;
                mPlaybackDelayed = false;
            }
            pausePlayback();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            synchronized(mFocusLock) {
                mResumeOnFocusGain = true;
                mPlaybackDelayed = false;
            }
            pausePlayback();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            // ... pausing or ducking depends on your application
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

References:

[Audio Focus Enhancements](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/audiofocus.html)

[Android O Features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html)

Comment: Because @kelebro63 just refrenced to a link and that link may be moved,changed or etc I provided more explanation plus code to prevent possible problems.

Comment: what is mMyHandler in your code? Its never declared. What does it do, what is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

To gain the focus use below (It will pause other player) :

```
 mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);       
 mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(null,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
```

To leave the focus use below (It will resume that player) :

```
   mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use 
[setOnAudioFocusChangeListener()](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/audiofocus.html)